# Mysql ALTER DATABASE fails with Errcode 5 on external NTFS drive

Tags: mysql

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) on how to change the mysql database character set to utf8mb4. The first instruction it gives is:

> ```
> # For each database:
> ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
> ```

When I try to execute it on my raspberry pi, I get the following error

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file './database_name/db.opt' (Errcode: 5)
```

How can I fix this?

It is likely of note that I have modified `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` so that the mysql datadir resides on an external NFTS-formatted hard drive. Hence, the size of the directory should not be an issue.

Because it is an NTFS drive, I doubt that it is a permissions problem. `chown mysql:mysql /mnt/theHDD/mysql` does not fail, but also does not modify the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `tmpdir` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` from `/tmp` to `/mnt/theHDD/mysqltmpdir` and creating that directory on the drive worked for me, but I do not understand why.